# How to combine in one sql query in extra column the result of 2 group by queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering the following `mdl_course_completions` table that describes a course completion for a user:

```
id,bigint
userid,bigint
course,bigint
timeenrolled,bigint
timestarted,bigint
timecompleted,bigint
reaggregate,bigint
```

To determinate if a course has been finished by a student, I use a predicate on the `timecompleted` field.

When this field is null, the student has not finished the course, but when this field is not null, that means the student has finished the course.

Thus, the count of the number of students that finished course by course is given by:

```
SELECT mdl_course.fullname,count(*) as "number of students that didn't finish courses"
FROM mdl_course_completions
  INNER JOIN mdl_course on  mdl_course.id = mdl_course_completions.course
WHERE timecompleted IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mdl_course.fullname
;
```

the result is:

```
| course name | number of students that finish courses |
|-------------|----------------------------------------|
| course 1    | 50                                     |
| course 2    | 200                                    |
| course 3    | 120                                    |
```

AND the count of the number of students that DIDN'T finished course by course is given by:

```
SELECT mdl_course.fullname,count(*) as "number student that didn't finish courses"
FROM mdl_course_completions
  INNER JOIN mdl_course on  mdl_course.id = mdl_course_completions.course
WHERE timecompleted IS NULL
GROUP BY mdl_course.fullname
;
```

the result is:

```
| course name | number of students that didn't finish courses |
|-------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| course 1    | 12                                            |
| course 2    | 12                                            |
| course 3    | 120                                           |
```

I wonder how can I combine this 2 queries to get in one query the results in an extra column such as:

```
| course name | number of students that finish courses | number of students that didn't finish courses |
|-------------|------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| course 1    | 50                                 | 12                                        |
| course 2    | 200                                | 12                                        |
| course 3    | 120                                | 120                                       |
```

I am using postgresql.In my opinion, this kind of stuff is not related to database system. I just don't know how to proceed to combine these 2 queries in one in an extra column with the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT mdl_course.fullname
,SUM((timecompleted IS NOT NULL)::int) as "number student that finish courses"
,SUM((timecompleted IS NULL)::int) as "number student that didn't finish courses"
FROM mdl_course_completions
INNER JOIN mdl_course on  mdl_course.id = mdl_course_completions.course 
GROUP BY mdl_course.fullname
```

Comment: this is working fine: thanks. I was not aware of the existence of 'conditional aggregation' concept. Any idea about how to add a third column that sums both students that finish and didn't finish course?

Comment: add `count(*)` to the query, which would give you the total.

Comment: ok, that makes the trick, maybe this would be better to use a `count` statement too for the 2 first others count student columns?

Answer (score 1):

From PostgreSQL 9.4 on, you can use the `FILTER` clause with aggregate functions:

```
count(*) FILTER (WHERE timecompleted IS NOT NULL)
```